# Argument type 'Any' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type

Tags: ios, swift

I Am trying to build a reminders app and am running into a problem.

i have a function,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    
    if saveButton === sender {
        let name = reminderTextField.text
        var time = timePicker.date
        let timeInterval = floor(time.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate/60)*60
        time = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval) as Date
        
        //build; notification
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertTitle = "Reminder"
        notification.alertBody = "Don't forget to \(name!)!"
        notification.fireDate = time
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
        
        reminder = Reminder(name: name!, time: time as NSDate, notification: notification)
    }
}
```

and it says, **Argument type 'Any' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type**
how do I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

You have to cast the unspecified `sender` parameter to the expected type to be able to compare it

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton,
  saveButton == button {
```

or with `guard`

```
guard let button = sender as? UIButton,
   saveButton == button else { return }
```

But if there is only one segue you can force unwrap the sender parameter

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
```

However in your example the `sender` parameter is unused anyway, so what's the comparison for?

Comment: You can direct use this ```if saveButton == (sender as? UIButton)```